# Nuxt JS PWA: How to make name/description of PWA dynamic (load from state)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I ve a NUXT JS Application. I am following [this documentation](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/setup.html) to create PWA for it.

My nuxtjs application is similar to multi-tenant and I want to change the name/short-name of my Progressive Web App in manifest on the basis of a value present in store(which is loaded with an API call).

Is it possible? What could be the right way to implement it?

Here is a similar issue on [github](https://github.com/nuxt-community/pwa-module/issues/225) , but it does not have any solution in it.

Comment: I think this is not possible